# Creating related articles using Codeigniter

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

**Controller:**

```
$data['similartopstories']=$this->frontend_model->homeallgallerypicssimilar();
$this->load->view('Moviestory',$data);
```

**Model:**

```
public function homeallgallerypicssimilar()
 {
    $query = $this->db->get_where('tbl_topstories',array('topstory_id' => $this->uri->segment(3))) ;
    foreach($query->result() as $row){ $tags = $row->meta_tag; }
    $match =  explode(",",$tags);
    $result = [];
    for($i = 0; $i < count($match); $i++)
    {
        $this->db->like('meta_tag',$match[$i]); 
        $this->db->from('tbl_topstories');
        $query = $this->db->get();
        if($query->num_rows()>0)
        $result[] = $query->result();       
    }   
    $sql="select * from tbl_topstories where topstory_id order by topstory_id desc limit 6";
    $query=$this->db->query($sql);
    return $query->result_array();

 }
```

**VIEW:**

```
<?php
foreach($similartopstories as $rec_article)
{

?>
    <a href="<?php echo base_url(); ?>topstories/<?php echo $this->frontend_model->clean($rec_article['article_url']); ?>"><div style="width:100px; height:140px; float:left; margin:10px;">
     <img src="<?php echo base_url(); ?>Topstoriespics/<?php echo $rec_article['topstory_pic']; ?>" alt="" width="100" height="100"  />
     <br>
    <h1 style="font: bold 11px Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;color: #006699;" class="nopadding" ><?php echo $rec_article['topstory_title']; ?></h1>
    </div></a>
    <?php 
}

?>
```

code is not working properly and there are only repeating the posts constantly so i need your help for that...thanks reply any time

Comment: And the question/problem/error is? What do you need from us? Just to see your code?

Comment: code is not working properly and there are only repeating the posts constantly so i need your help for that

Answer (score 0):

It is clear you are having problems, but you have to be more specific on yr issues, in order to get quick and specific answers.

From a quick glance, inside your model, you shouldn't use "$this->uri->segment(3)", make it as input for the model & it also should be in the controller.

```
$data['similartopstories']=$this->frontend_model->homeallgallerypicssimilar($this->uri->segment(3));
```

and

```
public function homeallgallerypicssimilar($topStoryID='') {
  $query = $this->db->get_where('tbl_topstories',array('topstory_id' => $topStoryID )) ;
  ...
}
```

The rest looks ok.

@Moulali , I can't complete the task for you, you have to do them yourself. I can help to guide you to it.

First of all, the MODEL

```
// MODEL
public function homeallgallerypicssimilar($topStoryID = '')
{
    $query = $this->db->get_where('tbl_topstories',array('topstory_id' => $topStoryID )) ;
    echo "<pre>";print_r($query);die; // print_r $query and check whether it suits yr needs....  IF STILL FAILS, tryout on yr localhost phpadmin SQL and check the output
    foreach($query->result() as $row){ $tags = $row->meta_tag; }
    // print_r $tags and check whether it suits yr needs
    $match =  explode(",",$tags);
    // print_r $match and check whether it suits yr needs
    $result = [];
    for($i = 0; $i < count($match); $i++)
    {
        $this->db->like('meta_tag',$match[$i]); 
        $this->db->from('tbl_topstories');
        $query = $this->db->get();
        if($query->num_rows()>0)
        $result[] = $query->result();       
        // AT THE END OF FIRST LOOP, BEFORE THE SECOND ONE START , print_r the $result and check whether it suits yr needs....  IF STILL FAILS, tryout on yr localhost phpadmin SQL and check the output
    }   
    $sql="select * from tbl_topstories where topstory_id order by topstory_id desc limit 6";
    $query=$this->db->query($sql);
    // FIX THE $sql AND THEN print_r the $query and check whether it suits yr needs... IF STILL FAILS, tryout on yr localhost phpadmin SQL and check the output
    return $query->result_array();

 }
```

THE CONTROLLER

```
// CONTROLLER
$data['similartopstories']=$this->frontend_model->homeallgallerypicssimilar($this->uri->segment(3));
echo "<pre>";print_r($data['similartopstories']);die; // print_r the $data['similartopstories'] and check whether it suits yr needs
$this->load->view('Moviestory',$data);
```

THE VIEW

```
// VIEW
<?php
echo "<pre>";print_r($similartopstories);die; // CHECK THE OUTPUTS whether it suits yr needs
foreach($similartopstories as $rec_article){
?>
    <a href="<?php echo base_url(); ?>topstories/<?php echo $this->frontend_model->clean($rec_article['article_url']); ?>"><div style="width:100px; height:140px; float:left; margin:10px;">
     <img src="<?php echo base_url(); ?>Topstoriespics/<?php echo $rec_article['topstory_pic']; ?>" alt="" width="100" height="100"  />
     <br>
    <h1 style="font: bold 11px Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;color: #006699;" class="nopadding" ><?php echo $rec_article['topstory_title']; ?></h1>
    </div></a>
    <?php 
     }
?>
```

I am quite sure you can find where went wrong,
Don't forget to upvote my answer!

Comment: i am not getting the related posts when i click on the article link and there are only repeating the same articles

Comment: Have you move the $this->uri->segment(3) to controller ?
If you did, still repeating same articles, then I would suggest you to debug one by one, step by step
check whether the $topStoryID is accurate
check whether your sql code has the correct output you wanted

Comment: I just realized towards the end of your model `function homeallgallerypicssimilar($topStoryID='')`  , the line : 

`$sql="select * from tbl_topstories where topstory_id order by topstory_id desc limit 6";`  

why are the code `where topstory_id` not complete?

Comment: i don't know please tell me how to complete the task

Comment: @MoulaliDeshamoni pls find additional answer above

Comment: I have a table named tbl_topstories (topstory_id,topstory_title,topstory_description,meta_tag,date)
so i want related posts from this table matched with meta_tag column for that please let me know how to write SQL code... thank you for replay